# Hyperledger Fabric Node.js SDK API failing on enrollment

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I've a Fabric network running on specific environment and I'm trying to integrate the [balance transfer node app example](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/master/balance-transfer/) with.

Well, I run the first command and I get the error bellow:

```
# Command
curl -s -X POST http://localhost:4000/users -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'username=Jim&orgName=Org1'

# Error
[2018-05-16 08:11:43.689] [ERROR] Helper - Failed to get registered user: Jim with error: Error: Enrollment failed with errors [[{"code":19,"message":"CA 'my-ca' does not exist"}]]
```

The parameter is on network-config.yaml:

```
...

organizations:
  Org1:
    mspid: org1MSP
    peers:
      - peer0
    certificateAuthorities:
      - my-ca
    adminPrivateKey:
      path: $PATH_TO_KEYSTORE
    signedCert:
      path: $PATH_TO_SIGNED_CERTS

...

certificateAuthorities:
  my-ca:
    httpOptions:
      verify: false
    tlsCACerts:
      path: $PATH_TO_CA_CERT

...
```

CA name was defined on specific Fabric CA container through `FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME` too.

Any idea what's goning on?

Answer (score 0):

Along with 'httpOptions' and 'tlsCACerts' in 'certificateAuthorities' there should also be 'caName', which should be 'my-ca' in your network-config.yaml.
Although in json, but for reference, you can check this link. [Fabric First Network Example, Connection file](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/v1.4.2/first-network/connection-org1.json)

Comment: Please include some crucial parts of that example in your answer here.